# Passing model to jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model

I am developping an ASP.NET Core application. I want to user the model send by the controller within my js.script file.

Currently I am using

```
var model =  @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
```

With this I can access the whole model within jQuery, but when I inspect the website, all the data from the model are visible.

How to prevent for this? I want to have a java object.

I searched a lot but without luck :(

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous/temporary object with just the properties you need, eg in C#:

```
var model =  @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(new { Model.Id, Model.Name, Model.Age }));
```

If you want it to use javascript conventions or map to different property names, add names, eg

```
var model =  @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(new { 
                                        id = Model.Id, 
                                        name = Model.Name, 
                                        ageOfModel = Model.Age 
                                      }));

console.log(model.id, model.name, model.ageOfModel);
```

remember this is .Net at that point, not javascript (so not `"id":` etc) then the console.log is back to javascript